# PHP Notice: Undefined index How To Fix This

Tags: php

i am getting PHP Notice:  Undefined index error in my site.

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  title in /home/kashan/public_html/ifunnygag.com/templates/wlol_v1/pages/header.php on line 41
>   [15-Apr-2013 06:36:42] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  url in /home/kashan/public_html/ifunnygag.com/templates/wlol_v1/pages/header.php on line 42

```
var opts = {
Line 40 message : '<?php echo $file['title'];?>',
Line 41 name : '<?php echo $file['title'];?>',
Line 42 link : '<?php echo $file['url'];?>',
    description : 'Click to see pic...',
Line 44 picture : '<?php echo $file['path'];?>'

};

FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', opts, function(response)
{
    if (!response || response.error)
    {
        console.log(response);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Success - Post ID: ' + response.id);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Show the `POST` request to this page.

Comment: `$file` is obviously not set or empty

Comment: Or $file is set, but $file['url'] is not? best way to settle that question: please add `print_r($file);` and let us know if $file is empty..

Comment: Please refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770836#12770836).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to leave the values empty if they are not set then use like

```
<?php echo isset($file['title'])?$file['title']:"";?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your $file array should have those indexes which u trying to echo, if it is there then do like this

```
"<?php echo $file['title'];?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check variables and array indexes using isset() or empty() before using them. I.e.

```
if (empty($file['url'])) {
 $file['url'] = '';
}
```

But you may also want to make sure that it isn't empty due to some other serious problem. I.e. Post fields that are not validated properly before being accepted. If a required post field is empty, you might want to reject the post request entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the quotes are causing the problem. Try,

```
"<?php echo $file['title'];?>"
```